# Should the SpaceX Starship static fire tests more closely match actual flight parameters?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship

Under the current 10 km flight program, all 3 Raptors are used at launch.  During the ascent, they shut down one at a time.

After a flop and free fall of several minutes, they are reignited, with the best 2 used for landing.

Major issues with leaks and thrust control have emerged with tests SN 8 - 11, whereas the SN 5 and 6 constant light vertical flights went well.

Using a 10 km vertical attitude only (with parachute instead of flop) was proposed, as SN 5 and 6 did not have an engine out/relight in their flight sequence, as a "bridge step" to what they are trying with SN 15.

Could they try the engine out/relight (also vertically) program during the SN 15 static fire test?

It seems on the 2nd light, the fuel could be exhausted, giving the technicians a rocket with its critical components intact to look at after the test.

Could a more robust static fire program for SN 15 help it avoid its predecessors fate?

Answer (score 11):

The static fire is just to make sure the engine will start, not to simulate the entire flight profile.

The problem isn't the engines themselves - they work just fine on ascent.  The problem is that the rapid transition from horizontal to vertical creates all kinds of interesting stresses and flow dynamics in the tanks and the plumbing, leading to insufficient or inconsistent fuel pressure to the engines.  This isn't something that can be easily sussed out on the ground, at least not at scale<sup>1</sup>.

They're going to blow up a few more prototypes before they figure this out.  As long as the root cause isn't the same twice in a row (and they aren't raining flaming metal death on populated areas), then they're making progress.

---

1. Yes, given time and money and space, they could build a test rig to suspend a full-scale Starship above the ground and rotate it from vertical to horizontal and study those flow dynamics with inert liquids.  That would be an engineering challenge all on its own, it would take a non-trivial amount of time and money to build, and probably would not sufficiently capture all the corner cases that flight testing will.

Comment: Agree. As long as they keep hitting the pad and missing the city, they can go at it for as many tries as they want.

Comment: "Rapid transition from horizontal to vertical creates all kinds of interesting stresses and flow dynamics"  Exactly!  The external can handle it, the internal is having issues so:  hang it from Tankzilla horizontally with a counter weight, then drop the weight and allow it to go vertical.  "Study flow dynamics with inert liquids"  That's step one cryro with nitrogen.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni And risk their million dollar crane if it goes pop like SN11 did? The prototypes may cost more than that, but the crane is a recoverable cost - sell it off to someone else when you're done.

Comment: @Saiboogu: I think they lease the big cranes rather than own them outright.  And the last thing you want to do with a crane is *swing* a load from it.  That’s a good way to wreck a crane.

Comment: The crane doesn't move at all.  The Starship rotates after the counter weight drops.  Inert liquids are used.  Liebherr is the crane manufacturer.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni I don’t see the advantage of dropping SN* from a crane vs flying it up and dropping it down? The former still results in the loss of the vehicle, and the latter gives more realistic data.

Comment: The latter does not necessarily lead to a loss of vehicle, as it's suspended from a crane, and it's using inert liquid (N2). @RobertDiGiovanni has a point here.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni the whole point in actually doing it is to actually do it.  Not to do something kinda similar but not really or to go all boeing and just do it all on a computer.

Comment: @AhmedTawfik I don't see it considering they don't actually want to reuse these things.  They want to see how they perform under real conditions and then build another. What a lot of questions like this miss is that building a lot of starships is just as much of the point as anything else.  They want to build 1000's of these. Every time they build one they are learning just as much about building (both the ship and the factory) as they are flying.

Comment: I just hope they don't have to build "1000s" before they get it right.  One of the keys may be the attitude of Starship right after flop.  It may be the camera angle, but it looks nose down, almost trying to glide.  I wonder if they can close some valves before this to keep the turbopump primed.  Restarting engines while the craft returns to vertical (to land) in around 2 seconds is going to be tough.  **Check out what Blue Origin just did**!.  Vertical descent at 450 mph with (tiny) airbrakes, engine restart at 6000 feet.

Comment: @eps of course I agree. However you can still move forward with respect to the testing regime. With a recoverable test apparatus, the same test can be repeated multiple times in a short period of time to produce the results needed. With a destructive test apparatus (free fall), the same test will take multiple months to get the same data. The experience in manufacturing can happen regardless of blowing the test item up.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni SN15 is supposed to have a number of design improvements over SN8-11 (which is why they skipped 12, 13, and 14).  And we have to remember they trashed a lot of F9 boosters when dialing in the landings for them.  I fully expect them to succeed within the next couple of attempts.

Comment: I'm with John Bode on this the flight test tells you things you cannot know you needed to ask in simulation.

Answer (score 8):

SpaceX has both vertical and horizontal Raptor test stands, to test operation in both orientations.

The relight issues could come down to engine performance/quality -- It is a new engine entering mass production, so they have growing pains to work out. This is why they are A) building so many and B) testing them in flight.

The relight issues could also come down to the extreme motions of flight and the flip - this is difficult to simulate on the ground, and another reason to test in flight.

And the engine failures have eclipsed this portion of the test campaign in the public eye, but remember that the entire descent profile is new ground. They have a lot of new hardware in the flaps, and lots of interesting/tricky avionics work to fine tune controlling the rocket on the aerodynamic phase of ascent. This means they have other reason to fly, beyond simply nailing the landing. Each flight gathers more flight time for the avionics systems.

So, now that the engines work well enough on ground and they have a lot of flight testing to do, they are testing engines in that more challenging (and realistic) environment).

Comment: so what is proposed is a vertical test *for the entire rocket*.  Both to have both is **very good**.  Horizontal to vertical stands do exist for intermediate missiles (of war).  One could be designed for the Starship.  "Building so many and testing" is admirable, but a bit like trying to teach golf to oneself by trial and error.  Many would die of old age before breaking 90.  "could also come down to extreme motions", this is why smaller steps to the flop-flip- powered landing might get them there with fewer proto builds.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni Building many prototypes is not a downside. They intend to build and fly thousands of Starships and the operation in Boca Chica is every bit as much a prototype factory as it is a rocket prototyping facility. 

They do test the entire rocket vertically - they pressure test, cryo proof, and static fire them on the pad before flight.

Comment: @Saiboogu It may not be a "downside" for Musk to throw away his own money testing endless prototypes, but as a fairly disinterested onlooker who has been working in aerospace for decades, the Starship program looks pretty much like the way engineering was done back in the 1960s, not in the 21st century.

Comment: @alephzero, 1960s-vintage engineering has certain advantages, such as rapid development.  The F-111 (60s engineering) went from initial specification to series production in six years; the F-35 (21st century engineering) still hasn't entered series production after 26 years.  I'm betting that 60s-style engineering is going to get Starship into orbit in less time and a lower budget than it's taking 21st-century engineering to launch SLS.

Comment: @alephzero What throws away more money, bending metal and pushing it to destruction, tweaking to go further each time -- Or spending a decade or more modeling an ultraconservative design that likely won't ever fly due to the project lifetime exceeding the political cycle? I have my ideas, you may have yours .. But conveniently time will tell the difference soon enough.

Comment: They got to the moon in the 1960s.

Comment: @alephzero they actually got stuff done in the 60's as opposed to "modern" engineering where you have the shuttle, SLS and (lol) starliner.

Comment: @alephzero With 21-st century engineering, you mean not getting anything done at all, in decades? Because thats whats happening to most programs right now. I encourage you to read Wayne hales blog, he has some very interesting pieces about actually doing stuff instead of thinking about it, endlessly. SpaceX brings results. The 60s brought results. It might not be so bad to re-visit some older approaches. rapid prototyping is in fact a staple of modern software development. Yes, they throw away prototypes, but at the same time they progress, instead of just designing in theory.

Comment: @alephzero: I guarantee they are retiring risk faster by building and flying prototypes, even if those prototypes blow up, rather than by relying on modeling and analysis.  Models are only as good as the data that goes into them, and there isn't a whole lot of real-world data on methalox FFSC engines being whipped around in highly dynamic maneuvers while burning.  Ultimately the only way to know that something will fly is to fly it.